# Как поменять цвет в ячейке с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Мне нужно в существующем файле .xlsx поменять **только цвет** текста определенной ячейки. Использовал такой код:

```
import openpyxl as opx
wb = opx.load_workbook('pattern.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws["A3"].font = opx.styles.Font(color='0070C0')
wb.save('pattern.xlsx')
```

Но это кроме цвета меняет и все остальное - название шрифта, размер и т.д. на значения по умолчанию.
Подскажите, как оставить остальные параметры не тронутыми.

Comment: просто интуитивно: `ws["A3"].font = ws["A3"].font(color='0070C0')` либо как-то так `ws["A3"].font.color = '0070C0'`

Comment: к сожалению, не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался! Чтобы поменять цвет шрифта, нужно указывать все параметры иначе они установятся в значения по умолчанию:

```
<openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name=None, charset=None, family=None, b=False, i=False, strike=None, outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=None, extend=None, sz=None, u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme=None
```

В моем случае получилось так:

```
ws[f'A3'].font = opx.styles.Font(name='Arial Cyr', charset=204, family=2.0, b=True, color='0070C0', sz=8.0)
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что должно быть более элегантное решение, чем явно прописывать все параметры. Нужно просто найти, как вытащить все эти параметры из текущей ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

[PatternFill](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html)

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
cell = wb.active.cell(column=1, row=1)

cell.fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color='0070c1', end_color='0070c1', fill_type='solid') 

cell.font = openpyxl.styles.Font(color='312BED', bold=False, italic=True, size=11)
```

Comment: ваш код меняет фон ячейки. Подскажите, как изменить цвет шрифта в ячейке